# What physical process can Metallicity(Z) of a galaxy tell us?

Tags: galaxy, cosmology, stellar-evolution, metallicity, galactic-evolution

For example, if there is a galaxy and its metallicity increase or decrease from high redshift to present day (We can see it from simulation like TNG or EAGLE). What physical process we can know?

Metallicity defined as (Mz/Mtot, where Z = any element above He)

My answer is that if metallicity of a galaxy increase, that means this galaxy is star-forming because new stars are thought to be with higher metallicity. I don't know if it is right.

Comment: Question:  what do you mean by "its metallicity increase or decrease from high redshift to present day"  We can only observe a galaxy at its current redshift. We can never observe a galaxy "in the present day" except for the Milky way. We can't observe the evolution of a galaxy, as we don't have billions of years.  We can observe different galaxies at different redshifts.

Comment: We can do it from simulation

Comment: You should mention some details about your simulation in the question.

Comment: "My answer" suggests that you are asking for someone to provide an answer for an exam or assessment question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the main processes that create elements heavier than Helium all involve stars:  Some elements are formed in stellar cores, some in neutron star collisions (but you can only get neutron stars from regular stars), some are formed in supernovae, some by neutron capture. All these processes require stars at some point.

So if a galaxy is becoming more metal-rich, that would mean that star formation is occurring. In particular, large stars are forming and dying.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, processes in new generation stars help form more metallic elements. Such processes are for example Nucleosynthesis and neutron capture processes thus New stars have more mettalicity as the Generation increases, Our Sun is a 2nd or 3rd generation star thus it has more mettalicity so the Star before it has less metallicity. Moreover the neutron capture process that occur in stars are s-proccess which are slow neutron capture process as it's name says. There are r process i.e Rapid Neutron capture process too which happen in Supernova nucleosynthesis and Neutron star mergers

Every time a new star is created it increases the metallicity of the elements to be used for other stars.

Star formation also increases the mettalicity of the next generation stars which is later given to the next generation stars using Supernovas and other star ends which gives an **Molecular cloud**, an star forming region which furthermore forms new stars

The [Metallicity (Z)](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/474/1/1143/4584473) sheds light on how fast is the star formation occur and thus the age of the galaxy and also about the Galaxy evolution

Other than Generation of stars, there is also Population of star represented by Roman numbers which is on a inverse scale i.e Population I has more metallicity than Population II

Comment: Star formation does NOT increase metallicity. It is only the deaths of stars (or at least near the ends of their lives) that increase the metallicity of interstellar gas. The formation of low-mass stars for example makes no contribution at all.

Comment: @ProfRob I think Star formation increases the mettalicity of the stars which is later spread to the galaxy be Supernovas and other star ends

Answer (score -1):

High metallicity indicates the presence of hot, massive stars - which implies it's a site where star formation exists *actively* - which in turn means there's a lot of gas left for massive stars to sustain numerous blue stars at once.

Moreover, any element past Helium in the periodic table is considered a "metal" here by astronomers. So lithium, oxygen (chemically non-metals) and likewise are all assumed "metals". The point of this is to separate stars that don't form lots of oxygen, which tend to be low mass stars (which shine red strongly than blue, and appears red) from the high mass stars (which as I stated earlier, shines blue). A low star forming galaxy would be dominated by low metallicity, looks red, and have exhausted available gas and begins forming low mass stars instead of high mass.

So in short, metallicity indicates how young and massive the stars in it are, which in turn can shed light into the galaxy's evolution and age.

Comment: Your answer seems very similar to the other existing answer. Is there anything that differentiates yours?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @fasterthanlight I've added a whole paragraph now.

Comment: Do you have any materials that you could cite?